# I am able to click on facebook comment box, but not able to type through sendkeys in comment input box using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

I can click on the facebook comment box but not able to type through sendkeys using selenium webdriver.

Comment: Do you have a bug report or console message?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot focus element